# Laravel 5.2 - ServiceProvider boot not working

Tags: laravel-5

Trying to use service provider to set a variables throughout all views pages that @extends('layouts.app') but not working, first I show the codes below.

AppServiceProvider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Auth;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // Using class based composers...
        view()->composer('layouts.app', function($view){

            $view->with('current_user', Auth::user());

        });

    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

When I visit the page that calls {{$current_user}}, it shows the following error

```
ErrorException in 5a5612347179ad88a6d4ebacc5d911a184c1b4ed.php line 14:

Undefined variable: current_user (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\soyegg\resources\views\shops\edit\showroom.blade.php)
```

Went through a several questions solved in the website and checked the followings but still failed:
1. AppServiceProvider is in config.app (default by Laravel 5.2)
2. php artisan clear-compiled
3. php artisan optimize
4. check whether there is compiled.php and try to clear it mannually but there is in neither storage/framework nor vendor.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `ServiceProvider` is working fine, you only need to change the way you passing data to the view. I've tested it myself and I can confirm that passing data to a view which later will be included with `@extends()` won't work. Instead you can use another methods:

```
view()->share('current_user', Auth::user());
```

Or using wildcard:

```
view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
    $view->with('current_user', Auth::user());
});

// wildcard with prefix
view()->composer('prefix.*', function ($view) {
    $view->with('current_user', Auth::user());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Rifki! Much appreciated. 

For the wild card it means that all pages will have such variable?

Comment: by using the share method, the page loads normally without error but the {{$current_user}} just does not have any value and I double check with {{$current_user->id}} and it says i getting property of non-object. I again check if {{Auth::user()}} itself works on the page and it works.

Comment: sorry to add another question here. I tried to add one more view()->composer below the current_user composer by calling $current_user->id but it says current_user is an undefined variable. Is there a more proper way of doing this ?

Comment: Just realized that `ServiceProvider` run before the `Auth::user()` is not yet available, so the solution could be put `view()->share('current_user', Auth::user());` on the `__construct()` method of your base controller.